How do I use the setAlignment method in HBox? JavaFX
I can't seem to get the setAlignment method to work to center my HBox of buttons, labels, and textFields. Everything I've read online makes me think I'm doing everything right but I think I'm missing something because this isn't working.
This is the section I'm having problems with.
        HBox edgeBox = new HBox();

        edgeBox.getChildren().addAll(addEdge);
        edgeBox.getChildren().addAll(vertex1Label, vertex1);
        edgeBox.getChildren().addAll(vertex2Label, vertex2);
        edgeBox.setSpacing(10);
        edgeBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

This is the output I'm getting.
enter image description here
This is the output I feel I should be getting.
enter image description here
This is the full code for the class if it helps. Other elements will be added to the pane when I can figure out my alignment issue. MyGraphPane extends Pane.
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Project4 extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        Button addEdge = new Button("Add Edge");
        Button isConnected = new Button("Is Connected?");
        Button hasCycles = new Button("Has Cycles?");
        Button dfs = new Button("Depth First Search");
        Button bfs = new Button("Breadth First Search");

        TextField vertex1 = new TextField();
        vertex1.setPrefWidth(30);
        Label vertex1Label = new Label("Vertex 1  ");

        TextField vertex2 = new TextField();
        vertex2.setPrefWidth(30);
        Label vertex2Label = new Label("Vertex 2  ");

        TextField output = new TextField();
        output.setPrefWidth(400);
        Label outputLabel = new Label();

        HBox edgeBox = new HBox();

        edgeBox.getChildren().addAll(addEdge);
        edgeBox.getChildren().addAll(vertex1Label, vertex1);
        edgeBox.getChildren().addAll(vertex2Label, vertex2);
        edgeBox.setSpacing(10);
        edgeBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        MyGraphPane pane = new MyGraphPane();
        pane.setPrefSize(500, 500);
        pane.getChildren().add(edgeBox);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        stage.setTitle("Project 4");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}

MyGraphPane
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;

import java.util.List;

public class MyGraphPane extends Pane {
    private MyGraph graph = new MyGraph();

    public MyGraphPane() {
       //this.setPrefSize(500, 500);

        createGraphics();

        //Adds a new vertex to the graph on click
        this.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            if(graph.getSize() == 0 && event.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY){
                graph.addVertex(new Vertex(event.getX(), event.getY(), "A"));
            }else if(event.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY)
                graph.addVertex(new Vertex(event.getX(), event.getY(), graph.getLastName()));
            createGraphics();
        });
    }

    private void createGraphics(){
        Circle circle;


        //Draws the vertices
        for(int i = 0; i < graph.getSize(); i++){
            circle = new Circle(graph.getVertex(i).getX(), graph.getVertex(i).getY(), 5);
            this.getChildren().add(circle);
        }

        Line line;

        int i = 0;
        for(List<Integer> list: graph.getEdges()){
            for(Integer J: list){
                line = new Line(graph.getVertex(i).getX(), graph.getVertex(i).getY(),
                        graph.getVertex(J).getX(), graph.getVertex(J).getY());
                if(!this.getChildren().contains(line)){
                    this.getChildren().add(line);
                }
            }
            i++;
        }

    }

    public MyGraph getGraph(){
        return graph;
    }

}

public class Vertex {
    private double x;
    private double y;
    private String name;

    public Vertex(double x, double y, String name) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }
}

package myproject.cmsc315_project4;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MyGraph{
    protected List<Vertex> vertices = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
    protected List<List<Integer>> edges = new ArrayList<>();

    //Constructor for an empty graph
    public MyGraph(){

    }

    public boolean addVertex(Vertex v){
        if(!vertices.contains(v)){
            vertices.add(v); //adds the new vertex
            edges.add(new ArrayList<>()); //creates a new array list for this vertexes edges
            return true;
        }else
            return false;
    }

    public boolean addEdge(Vertex a, Vertex b){
        if(a.getX() == b.getX() && a.getY() == b.getY()){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The vertices are the same");
        }else if(vertices.contains(a) && vertices.contains(b)){
            edges.get(vertices.indexOf(a)).add(vertices.indexOf(b));
            return true;
        }else
            return false;
    }

    //Get the size of the vertices array list
    public int getSize(){
        return vertices.size();
    }

    //Get the name of the last vertex in the list
    public String getLastName(){
        return vertices.get(getSize()-1).getName();
    }

    //Get a specific vertex
    public Vertex getVertex(int i){
        return vertices.get(i);
    }

    public List<List<Integer>> getEdges(){
        return edges;
    }

}


Your code has MyGraphPane pane = new MyGraphPane();. I could  not run it.

My guess is that you need to set edgeBox maxWidth to Double.MAX_VALUE.

Setting maxWidth to Double.MAX_VALUE unfortunately didn't work.

That was my guess. If you want a better guess, I would have to see the MyGraphPane code.

I added the MyGraphPane class. Along with the other classes used in it.

I think your issue is that you are adding the edgeBox to the MyGraphPane. I think you need to create a root node using VBox or BorderPane and add edgeBox and MyGraphPane to it.
Main
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

public class Project4 extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        Button addEdge = new Button("Add Edge");
        Button isConnected = new Button("Is Connected?");
        Button hasCycles = new Button("Has Cycles?");
        Button dfs = new Button("Depth First Search");
        Button bfs = new Button("Breadth First Search");

        TextField vertex1 = new TextField();
        vertex1.setPrefWidth(30);
        Label vertex1Label = new Label("Vertex 1  ");

        TextField vertex2 = new TextField();
        vertex2.setPrefWidth(30);
        Label vertex2Label = new Label("Vertex 2  ");

        TextField output = new TextField();
        output.setPrefWidth(400);
        Label outputLabel = new Label();

        HBox edgeBox = new HBox();

        edgeBox.getChildren().addAll(addEdge);
        edgeBox.getChildren().addAll(vertex1Label, vertex1);
        edgeBox.getChildren().addAll(vertex2Label, vertex2);
        edgeBox.setSpacing(10);
        edgeBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        
        MyGraphPane pane = new MyGraphPane();
        
        VBox root = new VBox(edgeBox, pane);
        root.setPrefSize(500, 500);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setTitle("Project 4");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}



That worked!! Thanks a bunch. This is only my second time using JavaFX so I'm still working out how all the different parts work.

The problem is that the HBox, as it was used, is only going to be as wide as it needs to be to hold its contents.  So the HBox is actually smaller than the OP thinks, and the children in it are, in fact, centred.
In order to do what the OP wants, which is to have the contents of the HBox centred in the window, the HBox needs to extend across the entire window.
The easiest way to do this is to put the HBox inside a StackPane.  StackPane's default behaviour is to make any resizable Nodes inside it grow to fill its space.  So StackPane will stretch out the HBox horizontally.
Here's a minimal amount of code to achieve this:
class ExampleApp : Application() {
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun start(primaryStage: Stage) {
        val mainPane = VBox().apply {
            children += StackPane(HBox(10.0).apply {
                children += Button("Button 1")
                children += Button("Button 2")
                children += Button("Button 3")
                alignment = Pos.CENTER
                style = "-fx-border-width: 2px; -fx-border-color: blue"
            })
            padding = Insets(5.0)
        }
        val mainScene = Scene(mainPane, 840.0, 700.0)
        primaryStage.scene = mainScene
        primaryStage.show()
    }
}

fun main() = Application.launch(ExampleApp::class.java)

Yes, Kotlin, but concepts are exactly the same as in Java.
This example has three containers:  An outer VBox, a StackPane inside it and the HBox inside that.  The outer VBox will only grow as much as needed to accommodate it's contents (the same way that HBox would grow horizontally).  This will limit the height of the layout, and it won't fill the entire window, which is 700px.
There's a blue border on the HBox, so that you can see its extents.
This results in this:

which is what the OP wants.
